# Wrap saga select effect into a promise to emulate DB query promise

Tags: javascript, redux-saga

I need to transfert a massive code from server to client.

On the server, the code does plenty of db query promises.

On the react/redux client, I want to wrap `yield select(state => ...)` into promises to simulate db calls for the code.

Tried stuff as

```
      return new Promise(function* (res, rej) {
        const val = yield select(state => state.user.app.email);
        res(val);
      });
```

But not working at all.

I want the promise to resolve when the expected value is found.

Thanks a lot

Comment: It's hard / impossible to understand your intention w/o context. I suggest you add more code. How is the function returning that promise utilized? It seems yield is used incorrectly. It should be in an iterator. The generator function is redeclared every time the promise is initialized.

Comment: Hi Marekful, Yes you're right, realized that since, the generator function is valid only if generator style kept all the way through. In the meantime I found a way to do what I need, about to post on this

Answer (score 0):

Found a way of doing it, trying to explain (sorry for with my little expertise on this).

- "Generator context" is launched from a redux "dispatch".
- From "generator context", it is easy to call promises and wait for resolution.
- But from promises launched out of "generator context", no way to start a "local" generator context.

Then all is to find a way to reenter "generator context" from a promise.

The trick is the following:

- The promise:

  - Get a promiseId
  - Save in an array a record with PromiseId, resolve and reject.
  - dispatch a redux event.
- The event is processed a in generator context, then the yield select can be used to extract the appropriate value.
- Once the value got, it calls a generic resolve that find the record in the array and resolve the promise.

Here is an example

```
// In generator context:

const effects = {
  *MAIN_ENTRY_POINT({ data, internal }) {
    // call a complex process that will use many promises to get data.
    const resp = yield sagas.call(ptaFunctions.complexProcess);
  },
  *ALU_QUERY(payload) {
    // back in generator context
    // the ALU_QUERY event is processed 
    // it calls a generator function to get the value (here: getUserEmail)

    const { fn, promiseId } = payload;
    const resp = yield sagas.call(ptaFunctions[fn], payload);
    // then it calls the "generic" resolve, which will find the appropriate promise record
    ptaResolve({ promiseId, resp });
  }
};

export const ptaFunctions = {
  complexProcess: async () => {
    // complex process wants the user email through a promise
    return await ptaFunctions.promiseGetUserEmail();
  },
  *getUserEmail() {
    // the select saga is available here
    return yield sagas.select(state => state.user.app.email);
  },
  promiseGetUserEmail() {
    // create the promise to get the user email. first get an Id
    const promiseId = uuidBase62.v4();
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // save the promise in a record
      promisesStack.push({ promiseId, resolve, reject });
      // push a redux event ALU_QUERY for that
      globalDispatch({
        type: "ALU_QUERY",
        fn: "getUserEmail",
        promiseId
      });
    });
  }
};

export const ptaResolve = ({ promiseId, resp }) => {
  // call the resolve function of the appropriate promise
  const rec = _.head(_.remove(promisesStack, r => r.promiseId === promiseId));
  rec.resolve(resp);
};
```

Doing such, I can use effects on a code that doesn't know at all about effects